# SQL Join query SUM() incorrect value

Tags: sql, mysql, sum

Query 1:

```
SELECT area, r_month, year, SUM(amount) as total, paid 
FROM payments_cable
GROUP BY r_month, year, paid 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, r_month), '%Y %M') DESC;
```

[image]

Query 2:

```
SELECT areas.user, payments_cable.area, payments_cable.r_month, 
payments_cable.year, SUM(payments_cable.amount) as total, 
payments_cable.paid 
**FROM payments_cable, areas
WHERE areas.user = "faruk"**
GROUP BY payments_cable.r_month, payments_cable.year,
 payments_cable.paid 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(payments_cable.year, payments_cable.r_month), '%Y %M') DESC;
```

When I run the query 2, the sum is multiplied by 6 and shows result 780

I need to calculate the sum where "areas table user = faruk is matched only on the payments_cable table.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Also, you should learn ANSI SQL JOIN syntax, the join syntax you are using has been outdated for 30+ years

Comment: sorry the image was the table screenshots

Comment: If you used ANSI SQL JOIN syntax it would almost certainly make it obvious what your issue is

Comment: There is no join condition between the two tables in the from clause leading to a carthesian join. Add a join condition

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide the `areas` table structure I can guess:

```
SELECT 
    areas.user, payments_cable.area, payments_cable.r_month, 
    payments_cable.year, SUM(payments_cable.amount) as total, 
    payments_cable.paid 
FROM payments_cable
JOIN areas ON areas.id = payments_cable.area -- join area table
WHERE areas.user = "faruk"
GROUP BY 
    payments_cable.r_month, 
    payments_cable.year,
    payments_cable.paid 
ORDER BY 
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(payments_cable.year, payments_cable.r_month), '%Y %M') DESC;
```